# How can I force invalidation of a running Cocoa program without additional custom code?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have multiple custom NSViews in my Cocoa program.   I am looking for a way to force them to invalidate without having to add additional code while the program is running.  If I were doing this with on Windows with the .NET framework, I would just drag part of my program offscreen and drag back on again.  Areas that was offscreen get invalidated when they come back on screen.  I haven't figure out how to do this with Cocoa - OSX.

Comment: pgb offered a programmatic way to do this and you seemed unsatisfied because it required code. Is this programming-related or not?

Comment: He's doing debugging.  Like, if you're staring at a misdraw on the screen and wondering "would this still look wrong if I forced a complete redraw", how do you make it redraw?  Or, if you had just set a break point in something that will happen when next things draw, how do you make it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimize the window and unminimize it.  That happens to force a redraw.

Answer (score 3):

The methods `setNeedsDisplay` should do it:

```
- (void)setNeedsDisplay:(BOOL)flag
- (void)setNeedsDisplayInRect:(NSRect)invalidRect
```

Docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setNeedsDisplay:)

Comment: My question was not clear.  I want to cause invalidation while the program is running.

Answer (score 1):

Windows on Mac OS X are buffered by the Window Server and can't be forced to redraw by moving them around the screen. The only way the user can force a redraw is to resize the window.

Why do you need to do this, though?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try F-script http://www.fscript.org/. It allows you to call methods on Cocoa objects while your program is running.

You could use it to call the `setNeedsDisplay:(BOOL)flag` or `setNeedsDisplayInRect:(NSRect)invalidRect` methods directly on the view you would like to invalidate.